# add new (missing) entry to referenced table from SQLFORM (SQLFORM.grid) in web2py

Tags: python-3.x, web2py

In this minimal case situation I have **table** with **filed referencing another table entries**.
When I'm adding **main_entries** entry, I have dropdown with entries from referenced table. When there isn't entry in referenced table I need, how can I create this new entry from this view (i.e. not leaving **main_entries** form)?

have this situation:

Model:

```py
db.define_table('main_entries',
    Field('type', 'reference entry_type' )
)

db.define_table('entry_type',
    Field('label')
)
```

Controller:

```py
def entries_edit():
    form = SQLFORM.grid(db.main_entries)
    return dict(form=form)
```

View:

```py
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
{{=form}}
```

Comment: it seem custom widget could be the way to achieve this...

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this by using the left option of SQLFORM.grid

> left is an optional left join expressions used to build ...select(left=...).

It makes sense to combine this with the field option to specify the fields of both tables which should be displayed.

> fields is a list of fields to be fetched from the database. It is also used to determine which fields to be shown in the grid view. However, it doesn't control what is displayed in the separate form used to edit rows. For that, use the readable and writable attribute of the database fields.

And don't forget to reference the leading table by the field_id option

> field_id must be the field of the table to be used as ID, for example db.mytable.id. This is useful when the grid query is a join of several tables. Any action button on the grid(add record, view, edit, delete) will work over db.mytable.

cf. [SQLFORM.grid signature](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#SQLFORM-grid-signature)

Answer (score 0):

You must specify relationship in query.
You can try something like this:

```
def entries_edit():
    query = db(db.main_entries.type == db.entry_type.id)
    form = SQLFORM.grid(query)
    return dict(form=form)
```